# Why does AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize return ERROR_BAD_VALUE (-2)?

Tags: android, audio-recording

I am testing this on a Samsung Galaxy S i9000.

```
int sampleRate = 44100;
int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, 
    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT);
```

It returns -2 `ERROR_BAD_VALUE`.

The native sample rate is 44100Hz, as returned by

> AudioTrack.getNativeOutputSampleRate(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM).

I have tried setting sampleRate to 1000, 8000, 22100 and 44100. I have also tried changing `AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO` to `AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO`. I have also tried `STEREO` (both `IN_STEREO` and `CONFIGURATION_STEREO`). I have also tried 16 bit encoding instead of 8 bit.

Update: my Manifest has `AUDIO_RECORD` as permission.

I keep getting -2 as a result. Why is this happening?

Comment: Hi, did this ever get resolved, or any insights? Thank you.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From the platform source file [AudioRecord.java](http://google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/media/java/android/media/AudioRecord.java):

```
static public int getMinBufferSize(int sampleRateInHz, int channelConfig, int audioFormat) {
    ...
    // PCM_8BIT is not supported at the moment
    if (audioFormat != AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT) {
        loge("getMinBufferSize(): Invalid audio format.");
        return AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE;
    }
    ...
}
```

Looks like your choice is 16-bit or nothing. :\

Comment: +1. He said he tried 16-bit as well, so the only other place in that method where ERROR_BAD_VALUE can be returned from in getMinBufferSize is line 472-475.

Comment: Thanks for the info. McStretch is correct though, I also tried ENCODING_PCM_16BIT.

Comment: This means that native_get_min_buff_size(sampleRateInHz, channelCount, audioFormat) returns 0. How can that happen?

Comment: I just ran your code with ENCODING_PCM_16BIT on a SGS and I get a return value of 8320.

Comment: @Reuben Scratton, that is very strange. I just tested it again with ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, and it still returns -2. What permissions have you set?

Comment: Update: I must have messed something up with my test. It does work now with PCM_16Bit. My apologies, and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In emulator it will always return -2. With the same code it will ok on real mobile.

Comment: sorry folk it returns -2 on real device as well