# AudioRecorder.getMinBufferSize() returns -2

Tags: android, audio-recording

When ever I run the getMinBufferSize() method in the AudioRecorder Class, the method always returns -2. Even when I change the sample rate, the encoding method, and the channel number. I have tried every combination possible, but it still returns -2. I know that the permissions are there for RecordAudio. If I comment out the line for the getMinBufferSize, and make the minBuffer 4096, the Audio recorder will initialize and record. This will only work when I have the sample rate set to 8000, and the recordings sound like trash. If I change the sample rate at all, the program will force close.

Edit:

```
bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(8000,AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_DEFAULT,ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
```

I am running this on the emulator, a Droid Eris, Droid 1, and Droid 2 Global

Comment: Can you post the code you are using.  Also, what phone are you developing on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the code for AudioRecord.java, there's really only 3 possibilities here:

- Your channelConfig is invalid.
- You're not using AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT. (8 bit's isn't supported right now.)
- The hardware doesn't support what you're asking it to record.

Source: http://google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/media/java/android/media/AudioRecord.java

See also: [Why does AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize return ERROR_BAD_VALUE (-2)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781781/why-does-audiorecord-getminbuffersize-return-error-bad-value-2)

Comment: I was using the 16 bit pcm, and the channel config was set to default. If I dont use the getMinBufferSize and set it to 4096, the audio will still record with the other settings im using, so the hardware hs to support the code.

Answer (score 2):

Try with these arguments, as these are the only set of arguments that are supposedly guaranteed to work on all Android devices:

```
AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(
 44100,
 AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
 AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT)
```

I've never had a problem using a sample rate of 16000 if 44.1KHz is too large for you.  Also, keep in mind that this is the *minimum* recording size.  Depending on your application, it would probably be a good idea to multiply it by 2 or 3 before you use this value to initialize the Audio Recorder.

If you are still having issues, make sure the audio source you initialize the `AudioRecord` object with is `MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC`.

Comment: Why is this? "Depending on your application, it would probably be a good idea to multiply it by 2 or 3 before you use this value to initialize the Audio Recorder."